# styles with height auto react native not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, styles, height

this is **expected result**-->

[image]

and this **is my result** -->

[image]

The colors are fine, that doesn't matter.
the problem is efectly in the line connector.

This is the code of  is a reusable component.

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";

type props ={
    color:any;
    type:string;
    getParentDimensions?: any;
}
const LineConnector = ({color, type, getParentDimensions}:props) =>{
    return (<>
    <View 
    style=
    {{
    borderWidth:0.5,
    backgroundColor: color,
    borderColor:color ,
    zIndex:-2 ,
    opacity:0.6,
    bottom:16.5,
    marginLeft: type === 'area' ? 45 : type == 'asset' ? 82 : 7,
    }}
    >
    </View>
    <View style={{
        borderBottomColor: color,
        borderBottomWidth: 0.5,
        width:'5%',
        opacity:0.6,
        position:'relative',
        alignSelf:'center',
        marginRight:10,
        top:5
    }}>
        <View style={{
            height:4,
            width:4,
            backgroundColor:color,
            position:'absolute',
            right:0,
            borderRadius:100,
            top:-2
            }}>
        </View>
    </View>
    </>
    )
};

export {LineConnector}
```

And this   in different components like this -->

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Pressable, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import ChevronDown from '@assets/images/chevron_down.svg';
import CounterAssets from './CounterAssets';
import BoxGradientLayout,{stylesCommon} from './BoxGradientLayout';
import BoxAreas from './BoxAreas';
import { LineConnector } from './LineConnector';

type propsLocations = {
    colors: any;
    locations?: [];
}

const BoxLocations = ({colors,locations}:propsLocations) => {
    const [showAreas, setShowAreas] = useState<number>(-1);
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({ 
        chevronDown:{
            transform:[{rotate: showAreas ? '180deg' : '0deg'}]
        },
    });
    const showViewAreas = (index:number) =>{
       if(index == showAreas){
            setShowAreas(-1);
       }else{
            setShowAreas(index)
       }
    }
    return (
    <>
        {locations?.map((loc:any, index:number)=>(
            <React.Fragment key={loc.id}>
                <View   style={{flexDirection:'row',display:'flex'}}>
                    <LineConnector  color={colors?.site} type='location' />
                        <BoxGradientLayout layoutType='location' colors={ colors?.location}>
                                <Text style={stylesCommon.name}>
                                    {loc?.name}
                                </Text>
                                <CounterAssets count={loc?.assets_counter} />
                        </BoxGradientLayout>
                        <View style={stylesCommon.containerChevron}>
                            <Pressable onPress={() => showViewAreas(index)} style={({ pressed }) => [pressed ? stylesCommon.chevronDownPress : styles.chevronDown]}>
                                        <ChevronDown fill={ colors?.location} fillOpacity={'0.03'} stroke={ colors?.location} />
                            </Pressable>
                        </View>
                </View>
                    {showAreas == index ? (
                        <View style={stylesCommon.childrenBox}>
                        <BoxAreas areas={loc.areas} colors={colors}/>
                        </View>
                    ) : null}
            </React.Fragment>
        ))}
    </>
    );
}
```

this is parent component style sheet and styles common (**BoxLocations**) -->

```
export const stylesCommon = StyleSheet.create({
    name:{
        paddingLeft:20,
        right:5
    },
    containerChevron:{
        top:5 ,    
        left:4,           
        alignItems:'center',
        flexDirection:'row', 
        elevation:5
    },
    chevronDownPress:{
        opacity:0.4,
     },
     childrenBox:{
        flexDirection:'column',
        position:'relative',
     }
})
```

Style Boxs Gradients -->

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        container:{
            flexDirection:'row',
        },
        containerGradient:{
            height:33,
            width:'auto',
            marginTop:10,
            alignSelf:'flex-start',
            alignItems:'center',
            flexDirection:'row',
            backgroundColor: colors,
            borderRadius:10,
            borderWidth:1,
            borderColor: colors,
            elevation:5
        },
        icons:{
            height:20,
            width:20,
            backgroundColor: colors,
            justifyContent:'center',
            alignItems:'center',
            borderRadius:100,
            left:4
        }
    });
```

I've been trying this functionality for several days and I can't find a solution.

Is it possible without installing libraries?

Any ideas?

**Thanks!!**

Sorry for the delay,i'am new. Below is my minimal reproducible example. I hope it is understood. The bullets represent the arrows that we see in the images and every time I enter each child the main line of the First Component separates and would have to continue until the last child without separating.

[minimal reploducible example](https://snack.expo.dev/KdQ1szjZq)

Comment: Could you create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on [snack.expo.dev](https://snack.expo.dev)?

Comment: Ok. Thanks, work in progress.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, here is my minimal reproducible example. I hope it is understood.
The bullets represent the arrows that we see in the images and every time I enter each child the main line of the First Component separates and would have to continue until the last child without separating.

https://snack.expo.dev/KdQ1szjZq

Comment: I wrote a answer for this somewhat similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75511810/20088324), I think you can solve your problem with the core concept of solution 2. It suggests to create a column for the line and a column for the children, that way to line won't be interrupted.

Comment: thanks. Right now I'm going to try it. thanks for your contribution. @RubenSmn

Comment: @RubenSmn I've been trying your proposal, but unfortunately I can't get what I'm looking for, the line of the first element always ends up breaking, thank you very much for the idea. If you come up with another, I'll be here. Thank you